# pandas dataframes merge with same column names, give priority to one

Tags: python, join, pandas, merge, dataframe

When merging and using the following MWE:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'A': [1, 1], 'B': [2, 22]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'A': [1, 1], 'D': [4, 44]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data={'A': [1, 1], 'F': [6, 66]})
df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=1, join='inner')
```

Output is:

```
    A   B   A   D   A   F
0   1   2   1   4   1   6
1   1  22   1  44   1  66
```

Any idea how it could be converted with cat or merge or some other function (without having to manually "drop" the common columns before or after the merge, and merge must be still inner) into the following output (assumes "priority" is given to `df1['A']`)?

```
    A   B   D   F
0   1   2   4   6
1   1  22  44  66
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transpose your dataframe, drop duplicates, and transform again.

```
>>> df.T.drop_duplicates().T
   A   B   D   F
0  1   2   4   6
1  1  22  44  66
```

Comment: Thanks. That will do, given that the values are the same. If the values are different I did something like as follows for the above example (works with same values also): `drops = [c for c in df2.columns if c in df1.columns]; df2.drop(drops, axis=1, inplace=True); drops = [c for c in df3.columns if c in df1.columns];  df3.drop(drops, axis=1, inplace=True)`